# Sitemap Without Plugin

Tags: wordpress, sitemap

i found this code from https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/324487

```
add_action( 'publish_post', 'ow_create_sitemap' );
add_action( 'publish_page', 'ow_create_sitemap' );
add_action( 'save_post',    'ow_create_sitemap' );

function ow_create_sitemap() {
    $postsForSitemap = get_posts(array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'orderby'     => 'modified',
        // 'custom_post' should be replaced with your own Custom Post Type (one or many)
        'post_type'   => array( 'post', 'page', 'custom_post' ),
        'order'       => 'DESC'
    ));

    $sitemap = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
    $sitemap .= '<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">';

    foreach( $postsForSitemap as $post ) {
        setup_postdata( $post );

        $postdate = explode( " ", $post->post_modified );

        $sitemap .= '<url>'.
                    '<loc>' . get_permalink( $post->ID ) . '</loc>' .
                    '<lastmod>' . $postdate[0] . '</lastmod>' .
                    '<changefreq>monthly</changefreq>' .
                    '</url>';
      }

    $sitemap .= '</urlset>';

    $fp = fopen( ABSPATH . 'sitemap.xml', 'w' );

    fwrite( $fp, $sitemap );
    fclose( $fp );
}
```

i need help to split each sitemap just 1000 post and my site have 40K+ post, so sitemap will create sitemap1,sitemap2,sitemap3.

can someone help me?

i need it for video sitemap, because most video sitemap plugin i know only support youtube and vimeo.

Answer (score 0):

**Are you running Wordpress `5.5`?** Since `5.5`, Wordpress already offer a default automatic XML sitemap. No action required.

> In WordPress `5.5`, a new feature is being introduced that adds basic, extensible XML sitemaps functionality into WordPress core.

- Source @ https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/07/22/new-xml-sitemaps-functionality-in-wordpress-5-5/#post-82168

Comment: WordPress currently implements and supports the core sitemaps format as defined on sitemaps.org. Sitemap extensions like image, video, and news sitemaps are not covered by this feature, as these are usually only useful for a small number of websites. In future versions of WordPress, filters and hooks may be added to enable adding such functionality. For now this will still be left to plugins to implement.